# Messaging between content script and popup script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a popup chrome extension that shows information about the DOM in the current page, which seems to require messaging. I've been able to send messages to the background, but I need the data to be specific to the current page, as the background is identical to all popups/pages.

In `popup.js`, I send a message when the DOM is loaded (should trigger when popup is clicked?)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getTableData"}, function response() {
    });
});
```

I also have a listener in the `contentscript.js` (and `background.js` for testing)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request.method == "getTableData") {
    console.log("table request found!");
  }
});
```

Then, when I activate the popup, the background console outputs `table request found!`, while
the console for the current page doesn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) instead of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send a message to a content script.